# Pandas converting a datetime object to string object using query() method

Tags: python, pandas

I have a line of code:

```
df_pva_review = df_all_active_pva.query('(`Next PVA Review Due`.dt.month == @lastmonth) or (`Last PVA Review Completed`.dt.month == @lastmonth)')
```

if I check the status of df_all_active_pva["Next PVA Review Due"], it is a datetime object, the query works as expected.

[image]

I am getting an exception when I then try to perform a similar query on the new data frame, dfa_pva_review:

```
 df_overdue_pva_reviews = df_pva_review.query('(`Next PVA Review Due`.dt.month == @lastmonth)')
```

Error is:  Fatal error occured: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

When I check the data type of df_overdue_pva_reviews["Next PVA Review Due"] it has become an "object type"....why would this happen?  Why would querying a data frame change the data types of the data frame it returns?

Update:

Actually noticed there is some code in between.

```
df_html = df_pva_review
df_html["Next PVA Review Due"] = df_html["Next PVA Review Due"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
df_html["PVA Review Initiation date"] = df_html["PVA Review Initiation Date"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
df_html["Last PVA Review Completed"] = df_html["Last PVA Review Completed"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
df_html["Last PVA Review On Time"] = df_html["Last PVA Review On Time"]
df_html["PVA Review Comments"] = df_html["PVA Review Comment(s)"]
df_html["PVA Manager"] = df_html["sltPVAManager"]
df_html["Product"] = df_html["sltProduct"]
df_html["PVA Status"] = df_html["Status of PVA"]
df_html.replace(np.NaN, '', inplace=True)
```

I suspect this is causing the issue as df_html is just a pointer to the same data frame.

```
df_html.replace(np.NaN, '', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Did you try removing `.dt` ?

Comment: `df_html["Next PVA Review Due"] = df_html["Next PVA Review Due"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')`: so it is changed from a datetime objecto to a string (which is generally an object in Pandas).

Comment: I think if I do this:  df_html = df_pva_review.copy(deep=True)  I am good, the issue is I am making changes into a dataframe I "think" is separate, but which is just a reference to the same one